# GMail stops sending push notification to WEB

Tags: push-notification, gmail, gmail-api

I've configured the push notifications following this guide and when calling the watch endpoint I get an expiration of about one week.

During this period I expect to receive notification to the Pub/Sub topic I've configured without the need to call the watch endpoint some time before the expiration date.

However what happens is that after about one day I'm not receiving notifications anymore and calling the watch endpoint doesn't help.

Why GMail has stopped to send notification to the subscription endpoint?

Comment: where is this happening, web or android?